# Embedded TradingView widget chart not showing in xampp

Tags: php, html, xampp

I am trying to embed a TradingView widget. When i am embedding widget in a html file and open it normally in browser it shows me the chart properly. But when i am embedding widget in a php or html file and try to open it using **xampp**, browser does not show me any chart.

How can i show the embedded chart while using **xampp** ?

Here is my embedded code part:

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Market Data</span> by TradingView</a></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-market-overview.js" async>
  {
  "showChart": true,
  "locale": "en",
  "largeChartUrl": "",
  "width": "400",
  "height": "660",
  "plotLineColorGrowing": "rgba(60, 188, 152, 1)",
  "plotLineColorFalling": "rgba(255, 74, 104, 1)",
  "gridLineColor": "rgba(233, 233, 234, 1)",
  "scaleFontColor": "rgba(218, 221, 224, 1)",
  "belowLineFillColorGrowing": "rgba(60, 188, 152, 0.05)",
  "belowLineFillColorFalling": "rgba(255, 74, 104, 0.05)",
  "symbolActiveColor": "rgba(242, 250, 254, 1)",
  "tabs": [
    {
      "title": "Indices",
      "symbols": [
        {
          "s": "INDEX:SPX",
          "d": "S&P 500"
        },
        {
          "s": "INDEX:IUXX",
          "d": "Nasdaq 100"
        },
        {
          "s": "INDEX:DOWI",
          "d": "Dow 30"
        },
        {
          "s": "INDEX:NKY",
          "d": "Nikkei 225"
        },
        {
          "s": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
          "d": "Apple"
        },
        {
          "s": "NASDAQ:GOOG",
          "d": "Google"
        },
        {
          "s": "MIL:FB",
          "d": "Facebook"
        }
      ],
      "originalTitle": "Indices"
    },
    {
      "title": "Commodities",
      "symbols": [
        {
          "s": "CME_MINI:ES1!",
          "d": "E-Mini S&P"
        },
        {
          "s": "CME:E61!",
          "d": "Euro"
        },
        {
          "s": "COMEX:GC1!",
          "d": "Gold"
        },
        {
          "s": "NYMEX:CL1!",
          "d": "Crude Oil"
        },
        {
          "s": "NYMEX:NG1!",
          "d": "Natural Gas"
        },
        {
          "s": "CBOT:ZC1!",
          "d": "Corn"
        }
      ],
      "originalTitle": "Commodities"
    },
    {
      "title": "Bonds",
      "symbols": [
        {
          "s": "CME:GE1!",
          "d": "Eurodollar"
        },
        {
          "s": "CBOT:ZB1!",
          "d": "T-Bond"
        },
        {
          "s": "CBOT:UD1!",
          "d": "Ultra T-Bond"
        },
        {
          "s": "EUREX:GG1!",
          "d": "Euro Bund"
        },
        {
          "s": "EUREX:II1!",
          "d": "Euro BTP"
        },
        {
          "s": "EUREX:HR1!",
          "d": "Euro BOBL"
        }
      ],
      "originalTitle": "Bonds"
    },
    {
      "title": "Forex",
      "symbols": [
        {
          "s": "FX:EURUSD"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:GBPUSD"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:USDJPY"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:USDCHF"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:AUDUSD"
        },
        {
          "s": "FX:USDCAD"
        }
      ],
      "originalTitle": "Forex"
    }
  ]
}
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Answer (score -1):

**user your ip or 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost**